# Spring boot internationalization not working when upgrading to latest version

Tags: spring, internationalization, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a small issue when upgrading my Spring Boot version to the latest one. My message.properties is not detected and internationalization is not loaded however when I run on version 1.3.0.RC1 everything is working fine and my messages load. I havent changed the contents of application.properties or the location of the messages themselves. I have done a lot of googling on this subject and never found the answer to it. My current application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
server.session.cookie.http-only=true
spring.resources.cache-period=0
spring.application.name=Cardinal
spring.messages.basename=internationalization/base
spring.mvc.locale=sv_SE
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=true
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
```

As you see they are located in a folder called internationalization and the file has the prefix of base. I do not know what to do with this and would very much appreciate your help. Have a good day fellow coders and may the code forever be in your favour.

Comment: Do you rely on autoconfiguration of a MessageSource? If so, a file called `messages.properties` is now mandatory to enable the autoconfiguration. I couldn't find the release notes for that, but i recall that problem from other questions here. If you only have locale-specific files like `messages_sv.properties`, then you have to create the default one.

Comment: It was mentioned in the release announcement: https://spring.io/blog/2016/01/22/spring-boot-1-3-2-released. It's always a good idea to have a default messages.properties as a fallback for anyone in a  locale for which you don't have a specific translation

Comment: Aha, I see makes perfect sense. I will test this and report back thank you both very much.

Comment: Works like a charm thank you both

Comment: @WheelchairGeek Just to make sure - you created a base.properties file in your "internationalization" directory to solve this, am I right?

Comment: exactly see my answer below for further details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by having a  default messages.properties as a fallback as mentioned in this blog post https://spring.io/blog/2016/01/22/spring-boot-1-3-2-released and by @Andy Wilkinson My message configuration looks like this:

messages.properties:

```
index.page.title=Welcome
page.brand=Cardinal
signin.header=Please sign in
signin.email.placeholder=Email
signin.password.placeholder=Password
signin.button.text=Sign in
forgot.password.link.text=Forgot password
rememberme.checkbox.text=Remember me
navbar.header.loginbutton.text=Sign in
```

messages_sv.properties:

```
index.page.title=Välkommem
page.brand=Cardinal
signin.header=Vänligen logga in
signin.email.placeholder=E-postadress
signin.password.placeholder=Lösenord
signin.button.text=Logga in
forgot.password.link.text=Glömt Lösenord?
rememberme.checkbox.text=Kom ihåg mig
navbar.header.loginbutton.text=Logga in
```

and application.yml

```
 server:
  context-path: /Cardinal
  session:
    cookie:
      http-only: true
  tomcat:
    uri-encoding: UTF-8
  port: 8082


spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
    mode: HTML5
    encoding: UTF-8
  resources:
    cache-period: 0
  application:
    name: Cardinal
  messages:
    basename: internationalization/messages
    encoding: utf-8
  mvc:
    locale: sv_SE
  http:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
debug: true
```

Hope this can help someone with a similar issue.